# Linux Apache config - You don't have permission to access / on this server?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

How can I tell Apache to point `127.0.0.1` to a specific folder like `/var/www/projects/mysite1/`?

I use `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and this is the config I have:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So if I change `/var/www/` to `/var/www/projects/mysite1/` and I tried to access `http://127.0.0.1/` on my browser after restarting the server, I get this error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

Any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve that is creating a VirtualHost.

1. In `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, create a `mysite1.conf` file. There, you should have this configuration:

   ```
   <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
       ServerName localhost
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/projects/mysite1/

       <Directory /var/www/projects/mysite1/>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
       </Directory>

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite1_error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite1_access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Disable the default VirtualHost and enable the created one:

   ```
   sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
   sudo a2ensite mysite1.conf
   ```
3. Reload the apache service:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 reload
   ```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer!